# How to rise PropertyChanged from background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

**Question was answered in other my thread, but i dont get full answer. I made some walk around and its work but im not very happy with this.
So im asking how to do it in MVVM patern.**

I got very frustrating problems with updating value in my textbox in View. Proprerty Message is updating from my callback but its not displaying in GUI. Property is correctly binding. There is noway i can do this. The reason is im not raising PropertyChanged on the UI thread, since im calling it from a callback. I'm trying, but nothing works. How to raise PropertyChange event on UI thread?

EDIT AGAIN REFRESH CODE:

```cs
namespace test
{
    public class MainViewModel  : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataExchangeCallback
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Message = "TEST1";
        }

        void IDataExchangeCallback.Result(string result)
        {
            Message += result;
        }

        public void Register()
        {
            InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(new MainViewModel());
            DataExchangeClient client = new DataExchangeClient(instanceContext);

            client.RegisterClient(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }

        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return this._message; }
            set
            {
                if (this._message != value)
                {
                    this._message = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Message");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; //ALWAYS NULL!!! BUT I HAVE INotifyPropertyChanged implement
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged; 
            if (handler != null)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My PropertChange is always null. WHY? It shoud subscribe to PropertyChanged when i'm using bindings.

**EDIT**
I Still Need Help

Comment: I'm not near a VS right now but you do have the solution partially marked out  :
 
 
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>{ handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)) });

Comment: It's **not** working and i don't know why.

Comment: Not quite sure, but could it be that you are passing a new instance of MainViewModel to: InstanceContext? Have you tried passing: InstanceContext instanceContext = new InstanceContext(this);

Comment: yes i tried no effect. Actualy i edited this post 38 mins ago and changed **this** to **new MainViewModel()**. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found solution!**

Apparently if you want use INotifyPropertyChanged you need to call it **explicitly** in code.

this.DataContext = mvm;

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
        mvm.Register();

       this.DataContext = mvm; //this you need
    }
}
```

Declaration in XAML is not sufficient:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

If someone can explain me why I would be grateful?

Comment: The xaml declaration of `<local:MainViewModel> as DataContext just defines what class intellisense should use when the designer lays out the window. You need to declare `this.DataContext = mvm` to assign an instance of that class at runtime to the window. The same goes for UserControls.